# Pascal - Set background to white (not grey, pure white)

Tags: winapi, console, pascal, freepascal, turbo-pascal

Is it possible to set console background in Pascal to pure white?
I'm no satisfied with

```
TextBackground(White);
```

I can use WinApi functions if that changes anything.
I know that background in console can be set to pure white (not grey). I once saw program with it. I think it was batch script. But I would like to achieve it in console.
Any trick will do. It can be very low level if there is no other way.

UPDATE.
I found batch command.

```
"COLOR arg"
```

I know I can use it in C++ by using

```
System("COLOR fc");
```

But I can't find any "System" command in Pascal.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code

```
swapvectors;  exec('cmd','/c color f0');  swapvectors;
```

This is a command prompt to set console window color

- f : Light white : Background
- 0 : Black : Text color
- You can go to cmd, type COLOR /? to know more

To use this code, you must uss DOS unit.

Sorry about my English, I am student.

Answer (score 0):

**Hooch**, you're right.

if I call `TextBackground(White);` or `TextBackground(White);` this get grey color.

For pure white need write `TextAttr:=$f0;`, where $**f**_ is background color (white for example), and where $_**0** is text color (black for example).

Answer (score 0):

You can change the background to white and then textcolor to blink and clear the screen.

`TextBackground(white); TextColor(Blink); Crt.ClrScr;`

Answer (score -1):

Right Click top of CMD window -> Properties -> Colors -> Choose whatever you want.

Also try `TextBackground(15);`

Comment: I want to do if from inside my program.

Comment: did you try 15 as parameter?

Comment: Yes. White = 15. I also tried typing "15". It is still grey. Not pure white.

Comment: HighVideo changes nothing. Or very little. But BG is still grey.

Comment: BTW, which compiler you are using?

Comment: Lazarus is the choosen one.

Comment: This is because of compiler.. Try to specify 7 explicitly, in general try all numbers from 0 to 15 :)

Comment: This is what I'm talkig about. http://i.imgur.com/WtKfX.png I tried all numbers. As you can see on pictrue, white BG is not white.